# Simplest way to return boolean from Observable

Tags: angular, rxjs, rxjs6

I want to get boolean for canActivate() method but nothing is working.
My code is:

```
  login() {
      return this.http.get<any>('http://localhost/auth');
  }
```

and I want to do somthing like this:

```
  canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot) {
    return this.authenticationService.login().subscribe(
      () => true,
    () => false
    );
  }
```

What is the correct way to do this?

Comment: You **cannot** return synchronous values from asynchronous methods. Here the `http.get()` method is async, so any statements that directly depend on it's response **must** be inside the subscriptions. In other words, you need to subscribe where the response is required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to subscribe in a `canActivate` method from a route Guard : In fact, Guard can return Observable and Angular will subscribe to it.

Just use rxjs `map` operator, such as :

```
canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot) {
  return this.authenticationService.login().pipe(
    map(response => /* do your stuff and return true to allow route access */)
    catchError(error => of(false)) // Auth failed : return false to prevent route access
  )
}
```

See more [here](https://angular.io/api/router/CanActivate)